# Google map marker disappears from map inserted via iframe

Tags: google-maps

I have found location on google map and get custom iframe code with marked location. However marker always disappears from map after several days.

Here is our website about page: http://witcraft.ru/about. Location of our office was marked, but now the marker has disappeared.

Also we have same issue on other websites. How can I avoid this behavior?

Regards,
Alexey Zakharov.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the only way to ensure that marker won't disappear is to use company website name during the query.

So if you want to mark your company that has your-company.com domain you should search it on google maps and when grab embeded code. Keep in mind that your-comapany.com domain should be mentioned in company description that you send to Google Places service.